# SQL Query to recursively find records with relationship based on 2 fields

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

Given the following data

```
OrderId UserId  Email   PostCode    Country
1       1       blah1   111         au
2       1       blah2   111         au
3       1       blah3   111         au
4       2       blah3   111         au
5       3       blah4   111         nz
6       3       blah4   111         nz
7       4       blah3   111         au
8       4       blah5   111         au
```

and this given input `UserID = 1`, `Email = "blah1"`

I need to write an sql query that gives me all unique records which recursively contains a match on UserId or Email

**Example Results**

```
OrderId UserId  Email   PostCode    Country
1       1       blah1   111         au
2       1       blah2   111         au
3       1       blah3   111         au
4       2       blah3   111         au
7       4       blah3   111         au
8       4       blah5   111         au
```

E.g

The first pass would produce the following based on `UserID = 1` **or** `Email = "blah1"`

```
OrderId UserId  Email   PostCode    Country
1       1       blah1   111         au
2       1       blah2   111         au
3       1       blah3   111         au
```

A subsequent pass on `UserID = 1` **or** `Email = "blah3"` would produce

```
OrderId UserId  Email   PostCode    Country
3       1       blah3   111         au
4       2       blah3   111         au
7       4       blah3   111         au
```

A subsequent pass on `UserID = 4` **or** `Email = "blah3"` would produce

```
OrderId UserId  Email   PostCode    Country
7       4       blah3   111         au
8       4       blah5   111         au
```

and so forth for **all** related records in a set to produce the **Example Results** shown above

Is this possible to do with a CTEs maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I think I've found the most appropriate solution to date.

I am open to a better way to achieve the same results or an optimization of what I have done.

```
USE [test]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[uspGetSimilar]    Script Date: 10/11/2014 12:49:03 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspGetSimilar] 
    @UserId varchar(20), 
    @Email varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
    -- set test src tables
    declare @src table (Id int,UserId nvarchar(20), Email nvarchar(50), PostCode int, Country nvarchar(50))

    -- inset test data
    insert @src 
    select * from (values 
    (1,'1','blah1',111,'au'),
    (2,'1','blah2',111,'au'),
    (3,'1','blah3',111,'au'),
    (4,'2','blah4',111,'au'),
    (5,'2','blah3',111,'nz'),
    (6,'4','blah4',111,'nz'),
    (7,'5','blah4',111,'nz'),
    (8,'5','blah6',111,'nz'),
    (9,'7','blah7',111,'nz'),
    (10,'8','blah8',111,'nz'),
    (11,'9','blah9',111,'nz'),
    (12,'10','blah10',111,'nz'),
    (13,'1','blah11',111,'nz')
    
    ) src(Id, UserId, Email, PostCode, Country)

    select * from @src

    -- declare table variables
    declare @Ids table (Id int)
    declare @Emails table (Email varchar(50), Searched bit)
    declare @UserIds table (UserId varchar(20), Searched bit)
    declare @Results table (Id int,UserId varchar(20),Email varchar(50),PostCode int, Country nvarchar(50))

    -- Merge Initial UserId into UserIds table
    if(@UserId is not null)
    begin
       merge into @UserIds u
       using ( 
         select @UserId as UserId
       ) t on t.UserId = u.UserId
       when not matched then 
        insert (UserId,Searched) values (t.UserId,0);
    end
    
    -- Merge Initial Email into Emails table
    if(@Email is not null)
    begin
       merge into @Emails u
       using ( 
          select @Email as Email
       ) t on t.Email = u.Email
       when not matched then 
          insert (Email,Searched) values (t.Email,0);
    end

   -- while both variables have something in them, there are potentially more matches
   while (@UserId is not null or @Email is not null)
   begin

      -- clear results  
      DELETE FROM @Results

      -- Main search query
      INSERT INTO @Results
      SELECT Id, UserId, Email,PostCode,Country 
      FROM @src
      Where (@UserId is not null and userId = @UserId) or (@Email is not null and Email = @Email)

      -- if results are found merge
      if (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
      begin
    
          -- merge new ids
              merge into @Ids i
          using ( 
             select Id from @Results
          ) t on t.Id = i.Id
          when not matched then 
             insert (Id) values (t.Id);

          -- merge new userIds
          merge into @UserIds u
          using ( 
            select UserId from @Results
          ) t on t.UserId = u.UserId
          when not matched then 
            insert (UserId,Searched) values (t.UserId,0);

          -- merge new emails
          merge into @Emails u
          using ( 
             select Email from @Results
          ) t on t.Email = u.Email
          when not matched then 
             insert (Email,Searched) values (t.Email,0);

      end

      -- mark variables as searched in thier respective tables
      UPDATE @UserIds set Searched = 1 where UserId = @UserId
      UPDATE @Emails set Searched = 1 where Email = @Email

       -- clear variables
      set @UserId = null;
      set @Email = null;

      -- reset variables to the next unserached value
      select top 1 @UserId = UserId from @UserIds where Searched = 0;
      select top 1 @Email = Email from @Emails where Searched = 0;

   end

   select * from @Ids

END
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a CTE for this, take a look at subqueries:

```
declare @src table (
    OrderId int
    , UserId int
    , Email nvarchar(50)
    , PostCode int
    , Country nvarchar(50)
    )

insert @src 
select * from (values 
(1,1,'blah1',111,'au'),
(2,1,'blah2',111,'au'),
(3,1,'blah3',111,'au'),
(4,2,'blah3',111,'au'),
(5,3,'blah3',111,'nz'),
(6,3,'blah3',111,'nz')) src(OrderId, UserId, Email, PostCode, Country)



select distinct *
from @src
where Email in (
        select Email
        from @src
        where UserId = 1
        ) or
        UserId in (
        select UserId
        from @src
        where Email = 'blah1'
        )
```

UPDATE question is changed, here is the new answer:

```
use guidion_test
go
if OBJECT_ID('demo_src') is not null drop table demo_src
create table demo_src (
    OrderId int
    , UserId int
    , Email nvarchar(50)
    , PostCode int
    , Country nvarchar(50)
    )

insert demo_src 
select * from (values 
(1,1,'blah1',111,'au'),
(2,1,'blah2',111,'au'),
(3,1,'blah3',111,'au'),
(4,2,'blah3',111,'au'),
(5,3,'blah3',111,'nz'),
(6,3,'blah3',111,'nz')) src(OrderId, UserId, Email, PostCode, Country);


declare @search_user int = 1;


with cte
as (
    select OrderId
        , UserId
        , Email
        , PostCode
        , Country
    from demo_src
    where UserId = @search_user

    union all

    select s.OrderId
        , s.UserId
        , s.Email
        , s.PostCode
        , s.Country
    from demo_src s
    join cte c
        on s.UserId = c.UserId
            or s.OrderId = c.OrderId
            or s.Email = c.Email
            or s.PostCode = c.PostCode
            or s.Country = c.Country
    )
select top 10  *
from cte
option (maxrecursion 100)
```

Comment: Ok this solution works for the data given, however if there are any more relationships between emails and ids it wont pick them up unfortunately, i've updated the question to show more related records

Comment: @Saruman that is quite a different question than you initially posted, even the title says 2 explicitly. I put a new code block under the first.